# Is there a way I can find back my comments deleted by others on Stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

I have a comment on a post on **Stackoverflow.com** which was deleted by someone long time ago. Now I'd like to find back the post to view some information, but I don't see that comment on my comments list, so I cannot find that post easily. Seems like, if the comments get deleted by others, they won't appear under my comment list anymore. This is really inconvenience. Anyone knows if there is a way to track down the comments deleted by others? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, I don't believe such a thing exists.  Once a comment is removed, it's *removed*.  I could be proven otherwise though.

Comment: @Makoto, I remember that I did see my comment on that post after some time it got deleted, not just after a few days.

Comment: Comments are not meant to be permanent, so no such feature exists for normal users.

Comment: Either you remember wrong, or it was posted by a moderator strictly for the purposes of moderation only. Deleted comments are not visible to regular users in any other circumstance.

Comment: @BoltClock, i think you got me wrong. i saw my comment which was already deleted by others on that post after logged in. If hadn't logged in, i wouldn't be able to see it of course.

Comment: Are you referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2098743/168175 by any chance?

Comment: @Makoto Pretty much everything (except users) is soft-deleted around here. We can look up deleted comments, comment revision history, etc.

Comment: @AnnaLear:  That makes sense.  I figured that comments were temporal enough to discard for normal users, but important enough for moderators to keep track of.

Comment: @Flexo, not this post, but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would likely be to just contact us via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page, link to the post you commented on, and ask for a copy of your comment back.

Note that we're unlikely to give you a copy of someone else's deleted comment. Something you wrote yourself, though, is easy enough to retrieve.

<sub>You *could* also flag for moderator attention, there's no easy/good way for moderators to respond to you with the contents of your comment, so that's not very useful.</sub>

Comment: "declined - <contents of comment anyway>"

Comment: When you do the contact us - all they do is point you back to post a comment on meta (and the link I was given meta.meta.stackoverflow.com) doesn't even exist!

Comment: Now that moderators have the ability to provide a comment when marking a flag as helpful does it change your answer?

Comment: @Servy The max length of the flag response is only 200 chars, whereas a site comment can go up to 500. So... for requests for one or two rather short deleted comments... I guess? As far as I know, this isn't a situation that comes up a whole lot either way.